# In js.erb ,how to use the array that defined in the rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, controller, each

My code is as follows:

**Controller:**

```
@snf1_ie_cases = Snf1Testcase.find(:all,:conditions=>["result_style = ?", 0])

respond_to do|format|
  format.js 
end
```

**XX.js.erb:**

```
<% for snf1_ie_case in @snf1_ie_cases %>
<% end %>
```

Then the error is:

> undefined method 'each'

How can I send the array of the controller to XX.js.erb?

Comment: Have you tried to use `@snf1_ie_cases.to_a` in the for loop ?

Comment: Thanks.But not useful,it also made error:undefined method 'to_a'